# how to exit from parent batch context

Tags: batch-file

I 'm trying to create a batch file as below.

```
@ECHO OFF
:Main
CALL :STEP_1
CALL :STEP_2

GOTO :EXIT

:STEP_1
REM some other logic here
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
  GOTO :ERROR
)
GOTO  :EOF

:STEP_2
REM step 2 logic
GOTO  :EOF

:ERROR
EXIT /b 1

:EXIT
EXIT /b 0
```

What I'm expecting is that the error handling in `:STEP_1` will exit from the whole batch file. However, what is happening is that it only exit from the content we created when we use `CALL`. `:STEP_2` will still be called even if there is an error in `:STEP_1`.

My question is, is it possible to accomplish my requirement? To exit from the whole batch file instead of the `:STEP_1` context, so `:STEP_2` won't be called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following `(GOTO) 2>NUL` combined with an exit, and that should do the job for you.

```
:ERROR
(goto) 2>nul & exit /b 1
```

Refer to [this](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6491) for more information.